# Onclick php update query

Tags: php, onclick, updates

Please help.. I'm abit on trouble with this code. I'm confuse! I use the `<form> <input type="submit">`. The ID is identified however if i click the one to be submitted the other ID appeared. Please Help! Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['ADD'])){
        $dvlbid=$_POST['dvlbid'];
        $docstate=XXX;

        $query="UPDATE dvlog set docstate='$docstate' where dvlbid='$dvlbid'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);

        header("Location: ../../modules/dv/add_dv.php?dvlbid=$dvlbid");
}
?>

    <form name="form" method="post">
        <table class="dvr_table" id="indextable" border="1"     style="border-collapse:collapse;" >
            <thead>
            <tr bgcolor='#666666' style='color:#FFFFFF'>
                <th><a href="javascript:SortTable(0,'T');">Book Code No.</a></th>
                <th><a href="javascript:SortTable(2,'N');">Amount</a></th>
                <th>OPTION</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            include('../../includes/ps_pagination.php');

$sql = "SELECT *,dvlbid,docstate FROM dvlog WHERE docstate = 'FOR_ENCODING' ";

$pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql, 20, 5);

$rs = $pager->paginate();
if (!$rs) { die("" . mysql_error()); }
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                {
                ?>

<tr bgcolor='#ffffff' />
<td>
    <?php echo $row["logbooktype"];?>-
    <?php echo $row["imonth"];?><?php echo $row["iday"];?>-
    <?php echo $row["logbookno"];?>
</td>
<td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row["amount"],2);?></td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="dvlbid" value="<?php echo $row["dvlbid"];?>">
    <input type="submit" name="ADD" value="ENCODE" />
</td>
</tr>

<?php $color="1"; }     ?>

            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="23" align="center">
                    <?php

                    echo '<div class="pager" >'.$pager->renderFullNav().'</div>';
?>
                    </td>
                </tr></table>
        </form>
```

EDITED:
Sorry about it. I deeply apologies. About the question when i click the ENCODE button as submit. Instead the dvlbid I click the other one is being selected. It makes the click dvlbid not the the one i click. It appears that it will select the 2nd dvlbid instead of the 1st one.

Comment: Sorry about the mess onegun. Hope you will consider it. and thank you Ed for editing it. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create 1 form to each `tr`. The way you are doing its generating many `dvlbid` values to the same form and theres no way to the browser know what you submit. I rewrite your code, creating one form for each `tr`, which I believe will work (although I don't understand very well your question):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['ADD'])){
        $dvlbid=$_POST['dvlbid'];
        $docstate=XXX;

        $query="UPDATE dvlog set docstate='$docstate' where dvlbid='$dvlbid'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);

        header("Location: ../../modules/dv/add_dv.php?dvlbid=$dvlbid");
}
?>

        <table class="dvr_table" id="indextable" border="1"     style="border-collapse:collapse;" >
            <thead>
            <tr bgcolor='#666666' style='color:#FFFFFF'>
                <th><a href="javascript:SortTable(0,'T');">Book Code No.</a></th>
                <th><a href="javascript:SortTable(2,'N');">Amount</a></th>
                <th>OPTION</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            include('../../includes/ps_pagination.php');

$sql = "SELECT *,dvlbid,docstate FROM dvlog WHERE docstate = 'FOR_ENCODING' ";

$pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql, 20, 5);

$rs = $pager->paginate();
if (!$rs) { die("" . mysql_error()); }
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                {
                ?>

<tr bgcolor='#ffffff' />
<form name="form" method="post">
<td>
    <?php echo $row["logbooktype"];?>-
    <?php echo $row["imonth"];?><?php echo $row["iday"];?>-
    <?php echo $row["logbookno"];?>
</td>
<td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row["amount"],2);?></td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="dvlbid" value="<?php echo $row["dvlbid"];?>">
    <input type="submit" name="ADD" value="ENCODE" />
</td>
</form>
</tr>

<?php $color="1"; }     ?>

            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="23" align="center">
                    <?php

                    echo '<div class="pager" >'.$pager->renderFullNav().'</div>';
?>
                    </td>
                </tr></table>
```

***PS:*** I really don't understand your question, if you are having trouble with a syntax error, or if the page are being blank, or if it behaves differently of as expected. I'm doing a blind guess here.

***PS II:*** What is that `XXX` on the 4th line?! Its a constant or an error?

Comment: Thak you Daniel. It work. I run through more test about it. +rep. ps i can't +rep it cause im below 15 reputation. god bless